# code not running in JSFiddle but working on site

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I'm trying to get an answer to another question and hoping adding a functioning JSFiddle will get me some responses. I'm working on the fiddle here:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jb8Nx/)

But it is giving me errors and not executing despite actually running on my site.

When I run JSHint, it tells me I am missing a semicolon in the first line of my JS, which is not the case.

The two external files are accessible, I can click on them and they pop right up in the browser.

The console on the JSFiddle page returns this 500 internal server error:

```
GET http://jobs.jsfiddle.net/random.js?callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_0 500 (Internal Server Error) moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:3146
inserters.bottom moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:3146
Element.implement.inject moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:3409
Request.JSONP.Class.send moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:12590
wrapper.extend.$owner moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:3798
Class.showJobs Sidebar.js?jobofferinsidebar:60
wrapper.extend.$owner moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:3798
Class.initialize Sidebar.js?jobofferinsidebar:34
(anonymous function) moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:5865
wrapper.extend.$owner moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:3798
(anonymous function) moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:3756
Layout.render LayoutCM.js?jobofferinsidebar:49
(anonymous function) (index):111
(anonymous function) moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:4624
(anonymous function) moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:212
Array.implement.each moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:329
invoke.fireEvent moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:4622
domready
```

which looks to me like a jsfiddle problem. This is the js code, but I'm pretty sure it's OK.

```
var i = 0;
var image_slide = new Array('image-1','image-2','image-3');
var NumOfImages = image_slide.length;
var wait = 8000;

function SwapImage(x,y) {       
    $(image_slide[x]).appear({ duration: 1 });
    $(image_slide[y]).fade({duration: 1});
}

function StartSlideShow() {
    play = setInterval('Play()',wait);  
}

function Play() {
    var imageShow, imageHide;

    imageShow = i+1;
    imageHide = i;

    if (imageShow == NumOfImages) {
        SwapImage(0,imageHide); 
        i = 0;                  
    } else {
        SwapImage(imageShow,imageHide);         
        i++;
    }
}
```

any idea why this would not be executing?

Comment: As a sidenote, why `setInterval('Play()', wait)`, and not `setInterval(Play, wait)`?

Comment: I don't have an answer for that, I found the code elsewhere. Now fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
play = setInterval('Play()',wait);
```

You should pass a function for the first parameter in `setInterval()`

```
play = setInterval(Play,wait);
```

Here is the fixed [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/timwzw/jb8Nx/2/).

Comment: Ahh, seems like StartSlideShow(); at the end was needed too. Just fixing the call to setInterval didn't quite get it there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the quotes around *Play()* in *StartSlideShow* function : http://jsfiddle.net/jb8Nx/1/

```
function StartSlideShow() {
    play = setInterval(Play(),wait);
}
```

Comment: This eliminates the errors, but the slideshow still isn't running. Other thoughts?

Comment: @AnonymousMan you should run the `StartSlideShow`, see my answer.